# file_get_contents, data from site

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hello i want some data from other site form **http://www.dailyfx.com/calendar** & i want only calander form that site. nothing else.
 also i retrive the data but hole the page data.

Kindly help me.

Comment: You'll need to write a web scrapper for the calendar table but be sure to check with them to ensure this is acceptable use of their site and content.

Answer (score 0):

Well i woudl jsut grab it in CSV format since they have those handy download links... alot easier than scraping all the HTML:

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0');
$dom->validateOnParse = false;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.dailyfx.com/calendar');
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$csvFileLink = $xpath->query("//div[@id='e-cal-control-bot-export']/a[contains(@href, '.csv')]/@href");

if($url = $csvFileLink->item(0)->textContent)
{
  if(0 === strpos($url, '/')){
    $url = 'http://www.dailyfx.com' . $url;
  } else {
    $url = 'http://www.dailyfx.com/calendar/'.$url;
  }

  $csvData = file_get_contents($url);
}

print $csvData;
```

Of course.. you might want to make sure youre in the clear legally depending on how you intend to use the data....